# Archive files x32 or x64?

Tags: c++, gcc, object-files

In C++, when you archive object files into a .a file, does it matter the platform?

For example I'm on an x64 platform compiling with x64 compiler, I compile a bunch of CPP files into .o files. Using AR.exe, I archive them into a .a file and distribute that.

Will the .a file be x32, x64 or interchangeable? OR does it depend on the program using the .a file?

Comment: A .a file simply contains the objects inside, so it will be whatever platform the source was compiled for. Using tools like lipo, you can distribute cross-platform .a files, however.

Comment: The .o files will already be as platform-dependent as it gets, `ar` won't magically fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that "compiling with x64 compiler" means that it generates 64-bit code, whether or not it is a 64-bit executable itself, then your .a files will be 64-bit code.  They are generated from your .o files, which are 64-bit binaries generated by your compiler.  The .a couldn't be anything more or different than the .o files are which constitute it.

Comment: Ooohhh I see. I was thinking that the .a files will be both some how and whatever program links to it will decide whether it is x32 or x64.. Thanks for clearing that up.